# OpenVPN will not connect

Tags: openvpn

I have created an OpenVPN connection to GigaNews' VyperVPN but it doesn't connect.  I followed all of their procedures found here: [www.giganews.com](http://www.giganews.com/support/vyprvpn/linux/pptp.html)

In my `/var/log/syslog` I find this:

```
Mar  4 16:57:45 X123 NetworkManager[1511]: 
<warn> connection /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/0 failed to activate: 
(1) Could not find source connection, or the source connection had no active device.
```

Comment: Why the title OpenVPN? That page talk about PPTP and not at all about OpenVPN.

Answer (score 0):

I use a different VPN service, but this may be of use to you.  The process works perfectly for me on Ubuntu 13.10.

It involves installing the OpenVPN Network Manager and tweaking a few settings.

https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/#ubuntu_openvpn_installer